# Error running ruby-2.3.1@rubinius/rake install --trace'

Tags: ruby, rvm

I wanted to install rbx in my PC. After installing rvm on my wsl(ubuntu), I try "rvm install rbx" command. But it has some problems when it's compiling.

The OS is Windows 10's wsl(Ubuntu), and installed ruby 2.5,rvm 1.29.9.

```
marisa@DESKTOP-IHFBOLV:~$ rvm install rbx --
rbx-4.1 - #removing src/rbx-4.1..
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
ruby-2.3.1@rubinius - #regenerating binstubs...........
rbx-4.1 - #downloading rubinius-4.1, this may take a while depending on your connection...
rbx-4.1 - #extracting rubinius-4.1 to /usr/share/rvm/src/rbx-4.1.....
rbx-4.1 - #configuring......................
rbx-4.1 - #compiling...................................................................................................
```

|

```
Error running '/home/marisa/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.1@rubinius/rake install --trace',
please read /home/marisa/.rvm/log/1573364723_rbx-4.1/rake.log
```

Because of the length of log (about 9k lines) , I show a part of the end of log :

```
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile
make
compiling openssl_missing.c
In file included from openssl_missing.c:21:
./openssl_missing.h:78:31: error: too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
EVP_MD_CTX *EVP_MD_CTX_create(void);
                          ^
/usr/include/openssl/evp.h:537:10: note: macro 'EVP_MD_CTX_create' defined here
# define EVP_MD_CTX_create()     EVP_MD_CTX_new()
     ^
In file included from openssl_missing.c:21:
./openssl_missing.h:82:22: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
void EVP_MD_CTX_init(EVP_MD_CTX *ctx);
                 ^
./openssl_missing.h:82:6: error: conflicting types for 'EVP_MD_CTX_reset'
void EVP_MD_CTX_init(EVP_MD_CTX *ctx);
 ^
/usr/include/openssl/evp.h:538:34: note: expanded from macro 'EVP_MD_CTX_init'
# define EVP_MD_CTX_init(ctx)    EVP_MD_CTX_reset((ctx))
/usr/include/openssl/evp.h:535:5: note: previous declaration is here
int EVP_MD_CTX_reset(EVP_MD_CTX *ctx);
    ^
In file included from openssl_missing.c:21:
./openssl_missing.h:90:25: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
void EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(EVP_MD_CTX *ctx);
                    ^
./openssl_missing.h:90:6: error: conflicting types for 'EVP_MD_CTX_free'
void EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(EVP_MD_CTX *ctx);
     ^
/usr/include/openssl/evp.h:539:34: note: expanded from macro 'EVP_MD_CTX_destroy'
# define EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(ctx) EVP_MD_CTX_free((ctx))
                             ^
/usr/include/openssl/evp.h:536:6: note: previous declaration is here
void EVP_MD_CTX_free(EVP_MD_CTX *ctx);
 ^
openssl_missing.c:53:19: error: too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
EVP_MD_CTX_create(void)
              ^
/usr/include/openssl/evp.h:537:10: note: macro 'EVP_MD_CTX_create' defined here
# define EVP_MD_CTX_create()     EVP_MD_CTX_new()
         ^
openssl_missing.c:53:18: error: expected ';' after top level declarator                                                 
EVP_MD_CTX_create(void)                                                                                                                  
^
             ;
2 warnings and 5 errors generated.
Makefile:229: recipe for target 'openssl_missing.o' failed
make: *** [openssl_missing.o] Error 1
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (2): [make...]
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:66:in `block in create_she\ll_runner'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:57:in `sh'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/usr/share/rvm/src/rbx-4.1/rakelib/core.rake:137:in `block in build_extension'
openssl_missing.c:53:18: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
EVP_MD_CTX_create(void)
/usr/share/rvm/src/rbx-4.1/rakelib/core.rake:202:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:81:in `each'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake- 10.4.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:81:in `each'
/usr/share/rvm/src/rbx-4.1/rakelib/core.rake:201:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_cal\l_chain'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequi\sites'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_cal\l_chain'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequi\sites'                                                                                                                  
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_cal\l_chain'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequi\sites'                                                                                                                  
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'                    
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_cal\l_chain'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'                  
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) \in top_level'                                                                                                           
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'             /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_leve\l'                                                                                                                      
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'        
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exceptio\n_handling'                                                                                                             
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'               
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/home/marisa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rubinius/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/marisa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rubinius/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => install => build:build => core:build => codedb:extensions
```

Comment: Did you read rake.log?

Comment: Yes ,it had. But it has 9k lines . I added it.